# The function plot(x,y) gives a blank graph window

Tags: matlab

I typed the following code in the command window, and the figure window comes out blank:

```
x = [1 2 3 5 7 7.5 8 10]
y = [2 6.5 7 7 5.5 4 6 8]
plot(x,y)
```

I am using MATLAB R2010a on Windows 10, 64-bit. Please help! I have looked up everywhere on the internet but couldn't find a solution.
[image]

Comment: check `plot(x,y,'r.')`

Comment: type plot(x,y,'r.') instead of just plot(x,y)?

Comment: yes. It puts `red dots`.

Comment: what is the function of just plot(x,y)?

Comment: It seems it doesn't help :)  default colors are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372462/what-is-the-default-matlab-color-order)

Comment: See if this post can help. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/166349-plots-return-a-blank-window

Comment: Have you tried changing the [`opengl`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/opengl.html) settings?

Comment: what should I change in those settings?

Comment: You could try software rendering to exclude opengl related problems: opengl software