# how to get good color separation for a few Matlab plot traces?

Tags: matlab, colormap

I need very distinct separation between several plot() traces. several means perhaps 2 or 3 or 5 time history traces or XY plots.

prism is nice with 7 distinctly separate colors but its yellow is hardly visible on the default white background.

Here's an example with default colors. They are quite nice but still somewhat muted pastels. I'd prefer brighter colors than default:

```
figure(1)
clf
x=1:100;
for i = 1:7
  y=i*log(x);  
  plot(x,y, 'Linewidth', 5);
  legendStr{i}=sprintf('line %i',i);
  hold on
end
grid on
legend(legendStr,'location','best')
```

how can I use prism or some other colormap without bright yellow? is there a better approach for plotting a few separate traces in the same figure with really clear color separation?

[image]

Comment: hello Cris, I've updated the question. The default colors are quite nice, indeed, but they are from a somewhat pastel pallette. Sometimes my preference is super-bright original colors like pure RGB, magenta, or cyan, but not yellow because of low contrast on white. I've found `colormap` difficult to use for years and Adam provided a clear, simple answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use `colormap` and `rgb`

`rgb` stands for **Red Green Blue**, just set how many percent(proportion) you want each of those main colors  in your  **final mixed color**

```
rgb = [0 0 0] ---> 0%Red + 0%Green + 0%Blue = Black
rgb = [1 0 0] ---> 100%Red + 0%Green + 0%Blue = Red
```

I use the scale `[0, 1]`, here `1 means 100%` and `0 means 0%`, you can set any value between `0 and 1`
The code is as follow

```
% Set the color you want using rgb
map = [0 0 0         %---> 1st color 
       1 0 0         %---> 2nd color
       0 1 0         %---> 3rd color
       0 0 1         %---> 4th color
       1 0.5 1       %---> 5th color
       0.2 0.5 0.75  %---> 6th color
       0.5 0.3 0.8]; %---> 7th color

x=1:100;
y = zeros(100, 7);
plt = zeros(1,7);
for i = 1:7
  y(:,i)=i*log(x);  
   % For each iteration use different map color, like map(1, :)-->[0 0 0]
   plt(i) = plot(x,y(:, i), 'Color',colormap(map(i, :)), 'Linewidth', 5);
   hold on

end

legend(plt,{'1st Color','2nd Color', '3rd Color', '4th Color', ...
    '5th Color', '6th Color', '7th Color'});
set(gca,'FontSize',20)
xlabel('x-axis','color', 'red', 'fontSize', 25)

ylabel('y-axis', 'color','red', 'fontSize', 25)
```

## Graph

[image]

Comment: thank you Adam. this is nice because it provides good control over color selections. this is important when reducing figures that fit a document's 2-column format. apparently the answer is - it's got to be manual. the revised original question includes a simple cell array for constructing a legend string that may simplify your answer

Comment: This is not how `colormap` works. You should just set `'Color',map(i, :)`. `colormap` sets the color map for a figure or axes, which affects gray-scale image display and surface plots. `colormap` is not at all used with lines. For lines, the axes property `'ColorOrder'` is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The `prism` palette has 6 unique colors, not 7. `cm=prism(6)` returns these 6 colors. The 3rd one is the yellow, we can remove it with `cm(3,:)=[]`.

We can now set the default color order for plots using the `ColorOrder` property of the axes object (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372462/what-is-the-default-matlab-color-order)):

```
cm = prism(6);
cm(3,:) = [];
set(gca,'ColorOrder',cm);
```

Now, when plotting to this axes object, those 5 colors will be cycled through (remember to set `hold on` so the axes properties are not reset).

To change the colors for all subsequent plots in the current MATLAB session, change the default color order:

```
set(groot,'defaultAxesColorOrder',cm)
```